# Replace newlines with literal \n

Tags: regex, sed

[This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed) has an answer to replace newlines with sed, using the format sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'.

This works, but not for special characters like \r, \n, etc.

What I'm trying to do is to replace the newline character by a literal \n.
Tried

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g'
```

and

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\\n/g'
```

also

```
sed ":a;N;$!ba;s/\n/'\'n/g"
```

but all to no avail. Sed keeps replacing the newline character.... with a newline character.

Thoughts?

### Edited after first answer:

For the sake of completeness the commands run are :

PostContent=`cat $TextTable | sed -E ':a;N;$!ba;s/\r{0,1}\n/\\n/g'`

Where TextTable is a variable linking to a text file containing a JSON output in the following format :

```
{"posts":[{"title":"mysupertest","slug":"bi-test","markdown":"##TEST
First things first !
To TEST this TEST TEST, click the download button below.
If you need more information about the TEST TEST, you can  read the Table of Contents below.

<a href='/assets/TEST.pdf' style='border-radius:5px; padding: 4px 15px; background-color:#008CBA; color:white; text-decoration:none; float:right;' download> Download </a>


##TEST OF TEST


###TEST TEST PLATFORM TEST GUIDE
WaTESTve TEST SetupTEST
TESTTEST
TESTTESTETESTTETSTTEST
TESTTESTTTETST
TESTTES
TESTTESTESSTSTESTESTTES
TEST","image":"http://localhost:3000/myimage.jpg","featured":false,"page":false,"status":"draft","language":"en_US","meta_title":null,"meta_description":null,"author":"4","publishedBy":null,"tags":[{"uuid":"ember2034","name":"implementation guides","slug":null,"description":null,"meta_title":null,"meta_description":null,"image":null,"visibility":"public"}]}]}
```

Comment: When you find yourself writing/using commands like `sed -E ':a;N;$!ba;s/\r{0,1}\n/\\n/g'`, doesn't it feel like it's getting just a wee bit arcane? If you post some concise, testable sample input and expected output I'm sure someone can show you how to solve your problem in a clear, efficient, portable and easily maintainable way!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This should work with both `LF` or `CR-LF` line endings:

```
sed -E ':a;N;$!ba;s/\r{0,1}\n/\\n/g' file
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.

Unfortunately I have the same result using this command.
I have updated the question with more details about the process.

Comment: Can you post output of `cat -vte file.json` in question as well?

Comment: Nevermind, I'm an idiot. Echo interpreted the newline character as a newline. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: [Here is a working demo of above command](http://ideone.com/plzyCP) - check output under **stdout** section.

Comment: Say, if I wanted to replace it with <BR/> for example, I could adapt your solution to sed -E ':a;N;$!ba;s/\r{0,1}\n/\<BR\\\>/g', if I'm not mistaken. Could you explain how your code works ? I don't get the first part.

Comment: You can use `sed -E ':a;N;$!ba;s/\r{0,1}\n/<br\/>/g' file` for using `<br/>` in replacement. `\r{0,1}\n` matches `\r\n` or `\n` in regex

Comment: You can also replace `{0,1}` by `?`, that seems more readable to me.

Comment: By the way, I wondered about this `-E` option, not mentioned in `man sed`, and it turns out it's an alias for the `-r` option, which means “use extended regular expressions in the script.”

Comment: @Niavlys yes that's right and `-E` is more portable option that `-r` across various *nix flavors.

Comment: This didn't work for me. It appeared to have no effect at all.

Comment: @user124384: Try awk solution by Ed

Comment: @anubhava: I've been using `cat` for a quarter century now, but never even bothered to look at the man page (DOH!); I'll keep `-vte` in mind for the future - thanks for that! :-)

Comment: `:a` sets a label named `a`. `$!ba` jumps back to label `a` for anything but last line.

Answer (score 145):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ cat file
a
b
c

$ awk '{printf "%s\\n", $0}' file
a\nb\nc\n$
```

or even:

```
$ awk -v ORS='\\n' '1' file
a\nb\nc\n$
```

Run dos2unix on the input file first to strip the `\r`s if you like, or use `-v RS='\r?\n'` with GNU awk or do `sub(/\r$/,"");` before the printf or any other of a dozen or so clear, simple ways to handle it.

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything else you should be using awk.

Comment: This is perfect for, for example, preparing an SSL cert to be added single-line to a json data bag. Worked on MacOS as well. Upvoted.

Comment: this works for me on macOS, I was trying to achieve the same to convert key/pem file to single liner for a json databag..

Comment: This would append an additional `\n` at the end.

Comment: @thetaprime what is "this" in your comment? If it's either of the scripts in my answer - no, it replaces each newline in the input with `\n` as requested by the OP and as you can see in my answer.

Comment: @EdMorton I think @thetaprime got confused as I initially did because of the \r. After re-reading your post the following worked for me: `awk '{gsub(/\r/$,""); ORS="\\n"}1' file`. Sharing this in case someone find it useful.

Answer (score 33):

You could do this using `sed` and `tr`:

```
sed 's/$/\\n/' file | tr -d '\n'
```

However this will add an extra `\n` at the end.

Comment: The last `\n` can be easily worked around with `$!`: `sed '$!s/$/\\n/' file | tr -d '\n'`. Otherwise, awesome answer :)

Answer (score 16):

With the `-z`option you can do

```
sed -z 's/\n/\\n/g' file
```

or

```
sed -z "s/\n/\\\n/g" file
```

Comment: `-z` seems to be available in GNU sed only, not in BSD sed; under macOS, the usual `brew install gnu-sed` option applies

Comment: @ssc I tried to keep the answer simple, `printf "%s" $(sed 's/$/\\n/' file)` is just another alternative.

Comment: @mvr's answer (see [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43967678/3814775)) is better than this one, since this one has two limitations, 1 as @ssc mentioned, the `-z` is GNU-specific option; 2 it can't avoid the extra `\n` at the end while @mvr's answer can. However, I still upvoted this answer, because it is a pretty cool option! Good to learn the `-z` option. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

In case it helps anyone, I was searching for the opposite of this question: to replace literal '\'n in a string with newline. I managed to solve it with sed like this:

```
_s="foo\nbar\n"
echo $_s | sed 's/\\n/\n/g'
```

Comment: That echo would do different things on different systems (use `printf '%s\n' "$_s"` instead) and not quoting the variable isn't safe, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes. In bash at least you don't need the pipe and sed at all, though, you could just do `printf '%s\n' "${_s//\\n/$'\n'}"`

Answer (score -2):

Here is little python script for replacing the '\r\n' with '\r' in directory in a recursive way
    import os
    import sys

```
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("Wrong arguments. Expected path to directory as arg 1.")
    exit(1)

path = sys.argv[1]


def RecOpOnDir(path, op) :
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        full_f = path + "/" + f
        if os.path.isdir(full_f):
            RecOpOnDir(full_f, op)
        else:
            try:
                op(full_f)
            except Exception as ex:
                print("Exception during proc '", full_f, "' Exception:", ex)

file_counter = 0

def WinEndingToUnix(path_to_file):
    global file_counter
    file_counter += 1
    file_strs = []
    with open(path_to_file) as f:
        for line in f:
            file_strs.append(line.replace(r"\r\n", r"\n"))

    with open(path_to_file, "w") as fw:
        fw.writelines(l for l in file_strs)

try:
    RecOpOnDir(path, WinEndingToUnix)
    print("Completed.", file_counter, "files was reformed")
except Exception as ex:
    print("Exception occured: ", ex)
    exit(1)
```