# Output File in One Line with Escape Sequences

Tags: bash, shell, escaping

I have a file like this:

```
This
    file
has
newlines
and
    tabs
```

and I want to generate something that looks like this:

```
This\n\tfile\nhas\nnewlines\nand\n\ttabs
```

How can I easily get this output?

Comment: Are there tabs in front of `file` and `tabs`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace newlines with literal \n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38672680/replace-newlines-with-literal-n)

Comment: and then replace `\t` with `\\t`.

Answer (score 1):

I just added an answer to [Replace newlines with literal \n](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38672680/3220113) that works here too.
Using the "new" `-z` option you can do

```
sed -z 's/\t/\\t/g;s/\n/\\n/g' file
```

or

```
sed -z "s/\t/\\\t/g;s/\n/\\\n/g" file
```