# Create JSON of environment variables name-value pairs from array of environment variable names with jq in bash script

Tags: arrays, json, bash, shell, jq

**Requirement:**

In a BASH script,

...iterate over an array of environment variable names as shown below:

`arr = ('env_var1' 'env_var2' 'env_var3')`

and, using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) generate a JSON of environment variable name-value pairs like below:

```json
{
 "env_var1": "env_var1_value_is_1",
 "env_var2": "env_var2_value_is_2",
 "env_var3": "env_var3_value_is_3"
}
```

**Current approach:**
Using this [stackoverflow question's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61807377/in-bash-create-json-object-of-key-filename-and-value-file-contents-given-sequen?noredirect=1&lq=1) as a reference

```
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}" |
  xargs -L 1 -I {} jq -sR --arg key {} '{ ($key): . }' | jq -s 'add'
```

where `arr` array contains the environment variable names for which I want the values, however I am unable to interpolate the `${environment_variable_name}` into the JSON's `value` in each key-value pair

Comment: Why don't you use [`env`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#%24ENV%2Cenv)?

Comment: If not limited to `jq`, [jo](https://github.com/jpmens/jo) is a pretty cool tool, to construct JSON on the fly when the input is from an external source e.g. a bash array in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
jq -n '$ARGS.positional | map({ (.): env[.] }) | add' --args "${arr[@]}"
```

Using `$ARGS.positional` with `--args` avoids the need to execute jq once per item in the array, and the `env` builtin is the thing you needed to pull values out of the environment.

Comment: Thank you @hobbs! I believe you could guide me on the below as well.

I input an object to my bash script which looks like `{"env_var1": "env_var_expected_val_1", "env_var2": "env_var_expected_val_2"}` and fetch all the keys (read: environment variable names) in an array i.e. `arr` with `jq -r 'keys[]'` which is inputed as the `${arr[@]}` to the above given command.

Is there a way I could use the jq `pipe` to combine all into one command?

Answer (score 1):

Since by assumption the variables referenced in `arr` are *environment* variables,
you could use `printf` along the lines of your attempt as follows:

```
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}" | jq -nR '[inputs | {(.): env[.] }] | add'
```

This also works with `gojq` and `fq`, and might be useful if your jq does not support $ARGS